# Clojure: how to get the *value* of a symbol as a keyword

Tags: clojure

I have some data from a file like this:

```
A abcdefghi...
B bcdefghij...
```

I would like to transform this into a bunch of maps, one per row:

```
A: abcdefghi
B: bcdefghij
```

But I don't see how to do this. I can get the two parts I want into symbols

```
part1

and

part2
```

But if use

```
#{(keyword part1) part2}
```

I get

```
{:part1 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}
```

But is there a way to get the value of **part1** instead of that name itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Ctrl-v TAB` echo text into a test file:

```
$ echo "A    abcde
B       bcdef" > test.txt
```

Test correct writing into file:

```
$ cat test.txt
A   abcde
B   bcdef
```

Then, in the clojure REPL, write functions:

```
(defn file2cells [fpath]
  (map #(clojure.string/split % #"\t") 
       (clojure.string/split (slurp fpath) #"\n")))

(defn keywordize-first [vec-list]
  (map (fn [[k v]] [(keyword k) v]) vec-list))

(defn file2maps [fpath]
  (into {} (keywordize-first (file2cells fpath))))
```

Apply the functions:

```
(file2maps "test.txt")
;; => {:A "abcde", :B "bcdef"}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do some reading and clarify your question.

This syntax:

```
#{ 3 1 4 }
```

creates a set of values, not a map.  You also need to clarify `part1` and `part2`- what are those?

Also, keyword literals have the colon at the beginning:

```
{ :a 1 :b 2 }    ; some map
```

There is a good [list of docs here](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).  Especially read "Getting Clojure" and the Clojure CheatSheet.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear; the data is ("A"  "abcdef...") and I get it into part1 and part2 with *first* and *rest* ... then a map with {A: "abcdef"} is the result I want ... but I didn't see how to evaluate part1 to get that.

Comment: You can't have `{A: "abcdef"}`.  You may have `{:A "abcdef"}` (keyword as map key) or `{"A" "abcdef"}` (string as map key).  Indeed you could have `{A "abcdef"}` (symbol as map key) - but symbols are usually cumbersome as map keys.